# Stanford NLP : How to get chunks

Tags: python, regex, nltk, stanford-nlp

so in nltk, we can specify a regex of POS tags to extract chunks of text as

```
sentence = [("the", "DT"), ("little", "JJ"), ("yellow", "JJ"), 
... ("dog", "NN"), ("barked", "VBD"), ("at", "IN"),  ("the", "DT"), ("cat", "NN")]

 grammar = "NP: {<DT>?<JJ>*<NN>}" 

 cp = nltk.RegexpParser(grammar) 
 result = cp.parse(sentence) 
 print(result) 
(S
  (NP the/DT little/JJ yellow/JJ dog/NN)
  barked/VBD
  at/IN
  (NP the/DT cat/NN))
```

is it possible to do something like this using stanford nlp?  what i would like to do is use stanford POS tagger to tag my text as i have found it to be more accurate than nltk's tagger. I guess once i have the tagged sentence, i could use the above code anyway. Still does Stanford NLP provide something out of the box to create chunks of text?

Also, i know that nltk 3 provides stanford NLP support. So how can i combine the two to get chunks of text? I would prefer to do this in python.

Comment: See https://github.com/alvations/nltk_cli

Answer (score 2):

If you know the patterns you want to consider as chunks, you can use [TokensRegex](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tokensregex.shtml) to cluster them.